# Count how often a period is in between an episode in different data frame in r

Tags: r, count

For an analysis concerning patient adherence I need to know how many patients were currently treated in different periods (weeks). I constructed treatment episodes, but now I need to know (count) how many patients were treated each week.

My dataframe with periods looks similar to:

```
> df <- data.frame(week = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
> df$start.week = as.Date('2020-01-01') + 7*df$week -7
> df$end.week = df$start.week + 6
> df 

  week start.week   end.week 
1    1 2020-01-01 2020-01-07
2    2 2020-01-08 2020-01-14
3    3 2020-01-15 2020-01-21
4    4 2020-01-22 2020-01-28
5    5 2020-01-29 2020-02-04
6    6 2020-02-05 2020-02-11
```

The treatmentepisodes are constructed with the package AdhereR and the data.frame includes (among others) the following columns:

```
> te <- data.frame(episode = c(1,2,3,4)) 
> te$episode.start <-  as.Date(c('2020-01-10', '2020-01-23', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-08'))
> te$episode.end <- as.Date(c('2020-02-01', '2020-02-27', '2020-03-01', '2020-01-25'))
> te

  episode episode.start episode.end
1       1    2020-01-10  2020-02-01
2       2    2020-01-23  2020-02-27
3       3    2020-01-14  2020-03-01
4       4    2020-01-08  2020-01-25
```

Now I am searching for the right code to construct a column `df$current.users` which counts the episodes that overlapped with the week. The output should be:

```
  week start.week   end.week current.user
1    1 2020-01-01 2020-01-07            0
2    2 2020-01-08 2020-01-14            3
3    3 2020-01-15 2020-01-21            3
4    4 2020-01-22 2020-01-28            4
5    5 2020-01-29 2020-02-04            3
6    6 2020-02-05 2020-02-11            2
```

Thereafter I also need columns with amount of 'starters' and 'stoppers' per week. If anyone know the right method, that will be so helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should episodes that span multiple weeks be counted as a new current.user in each week? Can a single patient have multiple episodes and how do you want to count them (just one current.user, multiple, count episodes in different weeks but collapse multiple episodes in one week)?

Comment: Hi! 
- Yes, current users is the total amount of users for a specific week. So 1 episode can cross multiple weeks, and the episode needs to be counted in every week. 
- A patient can have multiple episodes: In the weeks that an episode crosses, the patient is current user, if there is an episode gap, the patient is not a current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want, with two caveats below:

```
df$current.user <- sapply(seq_along(df$week), function(week) {
  sum(te$episode.start <= df$end.week[week] & te$episode.end >= df$start.week[week])
})

df

  week start.week   end.week current.user
1    1 2020-01-01 2020-01-07            0
2    2 2020-01-08 2020-01-14            3
3    3 2020-01-15 2020-01-21            3
4    4 2020-01-22 2020-01-28            4
5    5 2020-01-29 2020-02-04            3
6    6 2020-02-05 2020-02-11            2
```

Caveat 1: the numbers are different from your example. Unless I've misunderstood something, I think your example might be wrong (e.g. there is no episode in Week 1 as far as I can see, so the total should be 0)

Caveat 2: you have no patient identifier, so if Patient A has two episodes in the same week, these will count as two `current.user`s. I don't know if this is what you want (it's actually really the same user, who has come back within one week, but if you're really only interested in episodes, then this is not a problem). This can be fixed by counting the unique patientIDs instead of just using `sum` inside the `sapply` function, but you need to have a patientID.

Comment: You are right, the example was wrong and I edited the post. Secondly, the treatment episodes are constructed in a way in which the patient can have multiple episodes, but not in the same week. So that problem is dealt with in a previous step (using patient_ID). 
Moreover, I think your solution works, so thank you so much for your effort, it really helps me forward!